# Discord.py Change Name Of Command Without Changing The Function Name

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this which kinda works

```py
@commands.command(aliases=['8ball'])
    async def _8ball(self, ctx):
        foo()
```

Except when I run the help command it tells the function name (_8ball)

So what I want is to call it with "8ball" and not "_8ball" and that it shows "8ball" instead of "_8ball" in help

Comment: Please show a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `name` keyword-argument into the decorator

```py
@bot.command(name="8ball")
async def _8ball(self, ctx):
    ...
```

Comment: Ah that was simple. Thanks!

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped

Comment: Here is the link to the documentation where it was illustrated for more context. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=For%20example,%20to%20change%20the%20name%20to%20something%20other%20than%20the%20function%20would%20be%20as%20simple%20as%20doing%20this: